# How do I use && in a ternary operator statement?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I am trying to understand ternary operators. However, I am now stumped!
I want to use && in the statement.

This is the code that I am trying to create using the ternary operator:

```
if (eatsPlants === true &&  eatsAnimals === true) {
"omnivor";
} else { 
"undefined";
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
(eatsPlants && eatsAnimals) ? "omnivore" : "undefind";
```

Here is the whole code that I have so far:

```
var eatsPlants = true;
var eatsAnimals = true;
var category = 
eatsPlants ? "herbivore" : "carnivor";
eatsAnimals ? "carnivor" : "herbivor";
(eatsPlants && eatsAnimals) ? "omnivore" : "undefined";

console.log(category);
```

Comment: `"omnivor";` doesn't do anything. Your original `if` statement has no effect. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The last two lines before your `console.log` doesn't do anything. You are not setting any new value to any variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `&&`, but with `?:` syntax, and with syntax of JavaScript statements overall.

```
var category = 
eatsPlants ? "herbivore" : "carnivor";
eatsAnimals ? "carnivor" : "herbivor";
(eatsPlants && eatsAnimals) ? "omnivore" : "undefined";
```

is three separate statements: one assignment that depends on `eatsPlants`, and two evaluations whose results will be discarded. This will do what you wanted:

```
var category = 
    (eatsPlants && eatsAnimals) ? "omnivore" :
    eatsPlants ? "herbivore" :
    eatsAnimals ? "carnivore" : "undefined";
```

The reason this works is the precedence rules that say that `?:` binds from the right; i.e. the previous code is equivalent to

```
var category = 
    (eatsPlants && eatsAnimals) ? "omnivore" :
    (eatsPlants ? "herbivore" :
    (eatsAnimals ? "carnivore" : "undefined"));
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me understand how to use the ternary statement with the && correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using tradition if-else, a statement is what you put inside the if-else block. Simply putting an expression(which then resolves to a value) does nothing but giving the value. So there is not value assignment happens.

For ternary operators, it is an expression that resolves to a value, which you can assign to some variable

```
let category ;
if (eatsPlants === true &&  eatsAnimals === true) {
  category = "omnivor"; // statement
} else { 
  category = "undefined";
}



let category2 = (eatsPlants === true &&  eatsAnimals === true)? "omnivor": "undefined"; // expression
```